# Why do primes prefer the form $6n-1$ instead of $6n+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Noticed for all primes $< 5000000$ there are $174190$ primes of form $6n+1$ and $174321$ of $6n-1$.

At no point did the number of $6n+1$ primes overtake $6n-1$.

Any reason for primes having a bias towards $6n-1$?

Comment: It might be related to [this specific prime number race](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_race), although it's not the same.

Comment: The $2006$ *Monthly* article *Prime Number Races* (by Granville & Martin) cited in quid's answer in the linked dupe is a good place to begin studies on this topic.

Comment: See also Wikipedia's article on [Chebyshev's_bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias)

Comment: Chebychev's bias (the nonresidues seem to be preferred). On the long run, the ratio tends to $1$ and I guess the lead switches infinite many often like in the race between $4n+1$ and $4n+3$ , but I am not sure.